# Consistant List Item Height in Responsive Menu

Tags: css, height, html-lists

I'm having an issue with a menu on a responsive site and wondered if anyone could advise.

If the screen width is at a size where some menu items are on two lines and others one, the black menu dividers don't go all the way to the bottom.

100% height doesn't appear to work I've tried adding...

```
ul {display:table}

li {display:table-cell}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k_2_j/obzj8f8m/4/

100% height just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, but that doesn't seem to help and the reason I prefer float:left to display:inline-block is that the blocks sit tight when floated. I've changed the JS fiddle example and now the end block falls over due to small gap between each block.